# Selenium installed in visual studio code but module isn't found

Tags: python, selenium, visual-studio-code

I've installed selenium in vscode but when I try to run the program I get an error saying module isn't found. Also, when using from selenium import webdriver, I get messages saying that it is unable to import. I have installed selenium using pip. Is anyone able to help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think what's happening that your vscode is using a different version of python than the one you're installing selenium to

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have [selected the environment you installed into](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment) by either clicking in the status bar on interpreter version or run the `Python: Select Interpreter` command from the command palette.

Also note that running the `pip` command is problematic as you don't know which Python you installed into specifically. It is best to be specific by specifying the full path to the version of Python you want to install into and using `-m`, e.g. `/full/path/to/python -m pip`.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, searching for a fix I found that there is a bug that gives you the "Module Isn't Found" message.  After checking your path and you have the proper interpreter selected close VS Code and re-open it.  This fixed it for me.